# Ubuntu blocks access to services when not logged in

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, services

I'm not really sure what's going on here.  I have the following:

1. A fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
2. Jira 6.1.2 installed as per instructions from Atlassian.
3. Confluence 3.5.13 installed as per instructions from Atlassian.

What's happening is that as long as I maintain an active SSH session with the server I can access Jira and Confluence just fine.  From both the internal network and externally.

The problem, however, is that as soon as I disconnect the SSH session I lose the ability to access both Jira and Confluence.  It's just gone, poof.  The browser displays a blank page/404 error.  As soon as I log in again over SSH, the services are accessible again (I don't need to restart them or anything after logging back in...just authenticate via SSH and everything is magically working correctly again).

I also have an Apache2 instance running on the same machine.  This one works just fine even when I'm not logged in via SSH.  It seems like it's only Jira/Confluence that are affected here.

Any ideas on what might cause this, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an encrypted home directory and JIRA or Confluence depend on files anywhere under your home directory?

If so, when you log out, that directory is encrypted and only available again when it's unencrypted after you log back in.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I have.  And I put JIRA_HOME and CONFLUENCE_HOME under my home directory.  Moved them elsewhere and problem solved.